# Search & Compare Multiple MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use PHP to search for IPs and ad networks in a MySQL database.  Basically we rotate visitors between various ad networks to prevent the same visitor from being sent to the same network within a 24 hour period.

**ip_addresses table**

```
id, address, network_id
1, 120.110.140.223, 1
2, 120.110.140.223, 3
3, 115.157.247.46, 1
```

**networks table**

```
id, name, clicks, status, order
1, Random Name, 200, Active, 1
2, Example Name, 500, Inactive, 3
3, Other Name, 100, Active, 2
```

Basically when a visitor hits our PHP page, I need to be able to echo a specific `id` from the `networks` table.  It should be **the ID of the first network** that isn't already listed in the `ip_addresses` table for the visitor's IP address.  The networks should be ordered by the `order` column and should have `status = Active`.

I thought about using PHP to get a list of the `id`'s of all networks with their `status` set to `Active` and correctly ordered like this:

```
SELECT id FROM networks WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id ASC
```

And then just loop through until I reach the first `id` that isn't in the `ip_addresses` table for their IP. However, I wasn't sure how to do that loop or how to make it stop once the first `network_id` that isn't in the `ip_addresses` table is found.

If I need to clarify anything, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to make an auxiliary table with relations between users and active networks, delete the relations when active goes inactive. that way, in that intermediary table, you can lookup for the user, and delete once the network has been fetched, to continue to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NOT IN` from a sub-query by passing the user's IP

```sql
SELECT id
FROM networks
WHERE status = 'Active'
  AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT network_id
    FROM ip_addresses
    WHERE address = '$ip'
)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```